# "Less than ... it looked like ..."

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

Is this expression common? Example:

> Less than a mansion it looked like a castle: crenelated roof, lancet
>   windows, cylindrical towers with crosses on top.

The reason I asked is because I got [0](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22Less%20than%20a%20mansion%20it%20looked%20like%22&oq=%22Less%20than%20a%20mansion%20it%20looked%20like%22&gs_l=serp.3...4100.4966.0.5144.7.6.0.0.0.1.192.330.0j2.2.0.msedr...0...1c.1.61.serp..7.0.0.YeXwqZrHgLw) hits in Google.

Comment: You can find other examples like this if you relax the criteria of *mansion* and *house*.

Comment: A more common way to say it is *It looked less like a mansion than like a castle*, or *It looked more like a castle than like a mansion*. (The second *like* here is in each case optional, but it makes clear that you do not mean that it looked more like a castle than a mansion does.)

Comment: Not only is it not common, it's very confusing. In fact, I'd say it's nonsense. You could say either “Less/smaller than a mansion, it nonetheless looked like a castle” or “More than a mansion it looked like a castle”, but the way you have it now I just can't wrap my brain around it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a writers discretion. Meaning: though not large it had the exterior form of a castle and then goes on the describe what the writer believes are external features of such a building.